# Execute curl calls in loop until it matches number in output

Tags: python

I would like to make the following curl call in a while loop, until 1234567 is equal to the number generated in the curl output which is 1610348864. Each time a CURL call is made 1610348864 changes to a random number.

How can I do that using python?

**CURL CALL:**

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://xyz.website' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'number=1234567'
```

**CURL OUTPUT:**

```
"MIME CHECK OK: 1234567 not equal 1610348864"
```

Comment: Do you want to keep repeating something until you match a 10 digit random number? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Have you tried using the requests library?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yes. I would like to do that because its a random number that would repeat at some time.

Comment: Well yes, at some time... But the server will have blocked you IP by then. Just make a loop and iterate until the numbers match then.

Comment: That's fine. It's a test server.

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

The library used to make HTTP requests in Python is typically `requests`. To execute repeated POST calls to your url, you will need to define a script which imports that library. A typical request will look something like

```py
import requests

response = requests.post(
  url="http://yoursite.com", 
  headers={
    "accept": "application/json", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  data={"number": 12345},
)
```

Put a call like this into a while loop, which updates its control variable after each call with your response data. You may find it helpful to first do a single call and print various attributes of the response until you find the right key for the number you are interested in, likely to be somewhere in `response.json` or `response.text`.

Comment: `json.dumps()` doesn't create url-encoded data. It should be `data={'number': 12345}`